# Disordered texture displayed on iOS device powered by Unity3D

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, opengl-es

**Screenshot on iPhone6s :**

[image]

Unity3D version:`5.3.5f1`

Texture Format:`TrueColor (Not Compressed)`

iOS device:`iPhone6s iOS 9.3.4`

And this issue only occured on our trunk branch recently, and other branches do not have this issue.

So we are sure about is:

`Shaders` are correct.

`Meshes` and texture coordinates(uv) of each vertex are correct.

By using Unity Profiler, what can also be sure:

`Memory` in use is not too large ( compared with other branches )

By using `GPU Frame Capture`, I found that the texture is incorrect in the captured frame:

**GPU Frame Capture :**

[image]

Has anyone ever solved this issue?

Comment: So, what is your problem? Simply putting an image up does not explain it....

Comment: @Programmer The background texture ,and other textures are not displayed correctly

Comment: Did you try a reimport of the texture?

Comment: The problem seems to be with FBO format or Render Target Texture format.

Comment: @JeanLuc what do you mean?Reimpot in the Unity~ or reimport in the memory at runtime?

Comment: in the Unity Editor Project view, right click and select reimport. Also try to duplicate the image file with another name outside of unity. so that completely freshly imported without a preexisting meta file configuration.

Comment: @JeanLuc I tried to delete the Library folder,and it didn't work...

Comment: I found that my project is too large ,and the size of ipa file is almost 600MB+.Does it matter?

Comment: 600MB should not be the issue. did you try it with a newer unity version like 5.3.6 or 5.4.0?

Comment: @JeanLuc But if I delete some large textures,it works.    I'm using both 5.3.5f1 and 5.4.0.